# why I do not see my Icon in Android Option Menu?

Tags: android

I have the following code to generate a Menu Item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu1"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action1"
          android:title="@string/foo" />
</menu>
```

I see the Item in the menu, but I can not see the icon. Whats wrong?
I dont want to use it as the following:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

then I see the icon, but I dont want it to be in the Action Bar

Comment: You mean, you don't see the icon in the dropdown menu?

Comment: right, I just see the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the ActionBar / Holo theme, you won't see any menu item icons in the overflow menus, sorry.
I think you will get the old menu back when you apply a pre-Holo theme to your activity!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

       menu.getItem(R.id.your_item_id).setIcon(R.drawable.your_drawable_id);
    }
```